# Cannot access current post's ID in custom plugin

Tags: posts, plugin-development, loop, ajax

I have a plugin that prepends an upvote box to `the_content` of a single post, sends data via AJAX back to the main plugin PHP file and calls a function to update a database value on success.

Here is the PHP callback from the AJAX:

```
function update_parlay_points() {
    //Update Parlay Points field on database with points from Post request. 
    //global $post;
    //$post_id = $post->ID;     
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $points = $_POST['score'];      
    $update_points = "UPDATE wp_posts 
        SET parlay_points = '$points' 
        WHERE id = $post_id";   
    var_dump( $post_id );
    echo $update_points;           
    global $mysqli;
    $mysqli->query( $update_points ) or die( "Query failed" );
    wp_die();
}
```

In Chrome's Developer tools, this gives me:

> bool(false) UPDATE wp_posts SET parlay_points = '26' WHERE id = Query
>   failed

As you can see, I tried declaring the `$post` variable as global to account for failures due to being outside of the Loop. The content that triggers the AJAX request is prepended to `the_content`, so I am not sure if I need to "enter" the Loop again somehow. I tried `if ( have_posts() )` and `if ( is_single() )` before `get_the_ID()` with no success. The Loop, in general, really confuses me.

I have also tried accessing `$post->ID` from the action hook `the_post`. Strangely enough, I am able to successfully echo the current post's ID but cannot store it in a globally scoped variable.

```
$post_id = Null;
add_action( 'the_post', 'wp_store_post_info' );
function wp_store_post_info() {
    //Set current post as global variable. 
    global $post;
    global $post_id;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    echo $post_id;
}
function update_parlay_points() {
    //...
    global $post_id;
    //Do stuff with the $post_id...
}
```

This does not work either:

```
$GLOBALS['post_id'] = $post->ID;
```

I am certain that the above function is being called, because the correct `$post_id` is being echoed. However, when I click the upvote button I get:

> NULL UPDATE wp_posts SET parlay_points = '28' WHERE id = Failed Query

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, I tried declaring the $post variable as global to account for failures due to being outside of the Loop.

The problem is **not** that the post is *"outside of the loop"*, problem is that AJAX request is a completely separate HTTP request.

When you do an AJAX request, is just like you are opening a new window on browser and open the url in this separate window. It means that the script that handles the AJAX request knows **nothing** about the page that sent the request.

If you need to process a specific post in the AJAX request, you need to send the post ID to process as part of the AJAX request data.

Comment: This is probably the crucial bit of info I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Got it working! Simply echoed the id into a hidden div, then passed it back with the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

My suggesion is to use `wp_localize_script()` to pass the post id to your AJAX calls.
Something like this..

```
function my_script_enqueue() {
    global $post;

    $translations = array(
        'postID' => $post->ID
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', '/url/to/your/script.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'MyAJAX', $translations );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script_enqueue')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about sending the post id of the single post trough ajax as well? So if you create a hidden input that contains the id, something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
```

Then you can just pick the id and send it trough the ajax request, so your function will end up looking something like this:

```
function update_parlay_points() {

    //Update Parlay Points field on database with points from Post request.     
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $points = $_POST['score'];      

    $update_points = "UPDATE wp_posts 
        SET parlay_points = '$points' 
        WHERE id = $post_id";   

    var_dump( $post_id );

    echo $update_points;           

    global $mysqli;
    $mysqli->query( $update_points ) or die( "Query failed" );

    wp_die();
}
```

I would also check out the [$wpdb Object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), insted of using $mysqli to handle the DB quieres.

Comment: Tried echoing the $post_id into a hidden div in the prepended content, then passing that through the AJAX request. It isn't working right now, but it makes sense that it would. Unfortunately I have a final exam in 2 days, so will have to pick it back up after :(. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexFADev There are multiple ways to get the post id, and it depends on how your prepended post is called. You might try get_the_ID instead, or call global $post in the prepended content. Also try to return the id in the ajax request to see if you got the right id. Good luck on your exams ;)