# How to pass Post_ID variable from theme's Single.php to custom Plugin using AJAX

Tags: posts, ajax

After a lot of searching, I seem to have found that get_this_ID(); nor other iterations of it will work in an AJAX request. I'm admittedly a PHP noob, can someone please explain how [this guy here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198075/cannot-access-current-posts-id-in-custom-plugin) accomplished it? He says he "Simply echoed the id into a hidden div, then passed it back with the AJAX call."

My code is below.

```
if(wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'checkbox') !== false) {

     global $post; 
     $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
     $post_ID = $post->ID; 

      $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

       $dataArray[$post_ID] = isset($dataArray['second_checkbox']) ? true : false;

      if($user_ID != NULL) {
        foreach($dataArray as $key=>$value) {

          $status = update_user_meta($user_ID, $key, $value);

        }

        //ajaxStatus('success', 'Meta fields updated.', $post_ID);
        ajaxStatus('success', 'Meta fields updated.', $dataArray);
```

It generates a blank value for $post_ID in the console.

```
{"status":"success","message":"Meta fields updated.","data":{"":false}}
```

But In the single.php page, the $post_ID is found and the echo works

```
<?php 
global $wp_query; 
$post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post_ID = $post->ID; 
?>                              <div id="test"><?php echo($post_ID); ?></div>
```

Javascript is here

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var response;
    $('#checkbox').on('submit',function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.post( checkbox.ajaxurl, {
          action : 'submit_checkboxes',
          nonce : checkbox.nonce,
          post : $(this).serialize()
      },
      function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          responseSuccess(response);
      });

    return false;
    });
    function responseSuccess(data) {

    response = JSON.parse(data);

    if(response.status === 'success') {
      $('#checkbox-message').text(response.message);
    } else {
      $('#checkbox-message').text(response.message);
    }
    }   });
```

This is the ajax

```
function ajaxStatus($status, $message, $data = NULL) {

  $response = array (
    'status' => $status,
    'message' => $message,
    'data' => $data
    //'data' => $post_ID
    );
  $output = json_encode($response);

  exit($output);

}
```

Comment: Where is the javascript code that makes the ajax request? That's where you need to get and pass the post ID.

Comment: can you share your ajax call too?

Comment: I just added them to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something in your code; but:

1. you need to "move" the content of your `test` div to a JS variable that can then be used in your Ajax (or use the div value directly in your $.post.

   e.g.   `var postID = $('#test').val();`
2. then use it to pass the needed info to your server

   ```
   $.post( checkbox.ajaxurl, {
      action : 'submit_checkboxes',
      nonce : checkbox.nonce,
      thispost : postID,
      post : $(this).serialize()
     },
     function(response) {whatever... }
   );
   ```
3. in your PHP use say `intval($_POST['thispost'])` to obtain the post id and use accordingly.

Note: not tested & I tend to use `jQuery.ajax` with a data string of values instead of `jQuery.post`

Comment: I really appreciate all your help. It helped point me to the/an answer! Though I didn't use the code directly, it led me to logically follow the flow of information back to the form from which I was pulling. Instead of having the form embedded in the post pages themselves, I put the form in the single.php file so it was universally applied to all posts. Then  I simply applied a <?php echo ($post_ID) ?>  into to the "for", "ID", and "name" fields of the inputs.  Thanks Again!

Comment: Glad it helped & its good you posted your end solution - it may be of use to others wishing to apply something to all posts.